# Laravel Queue::later needs another Queue::later to trigger

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, beanstalkd

I have set up a laravel queue and am using beanstalkd.

If I use Queue::later() then the job is queued, but it doesn't run at the specified time until I send another job with Queue::later() after the scheduled time.

Am I missing something from my setup, or could my queues have got messed up somehow, if so how can I purge everything and get it running normally again.

I am using the setup detailed here
http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4

The server with the problem was Ubuntu 12.04

I've just set it all up on a new server with Ubuntu 13.10 and it's working as expected.

I'd like to know how it was possible for the queue to end up in this state and how to go about fixing it.  Laravel reports no failed jobs.

Comment: Sure you didn't forget to run php artisan queue:listen?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Debian wheezy (7.6)

Issue is with the version of beanstalkd that is considered stable. (v 1.4.6-1 is one version I confirm that there is an issue with) 
The issue was fixed in a subsequent version, not sure which one, but updating your version of Ubuntu changed the version that was considered stable (and thus the version installed) to a version that had corrected this issue.
Latest version at the time of this post is v1.10-1, though 1.9-2 should also be free from this bug.

So for anyone with this issue, either try updating your version of beanstalkd, or use a different queue provider (If you want to stay with a local service, redis would be your best option).

Comment: for the record, issuing Queue::push or Mail::Queue will also trigger outstanding items